# Is it necessary to lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, stdmutex

I met a question in [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/description/). I have viewed some solutions in the [discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/discuss/). But my [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/discuss/368053/cmutexcondition_variableflag) is different from others because I do not use the `lock` in the method `first`. I wonder whether my code is correct. Besides, can you give me some advice about my code?

I think it is not necessary to use `unique_lock` in method `void first(function<void()> printFirst)` like `void second(function<void()> printSecond)`, is it right?

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {

    }

    void first(function<void()> printFirst) {
        // cout<<1<<endl;
        // printFirst() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
        // mtx.lock();
        printFirst();
        flag=1;
        // mtx.unlock();
        cond.notify_all();
        // cout<<11<<endl;
    }

    void second(function<void()> printSecond) {
        // cout<<2<<endl;
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(mtx);
            cond.wait(lk,[this](){return flag==1;});
            // printSecond() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
            printSecond();
            flag=2;
        }

        // cout<<22<<endl;
        cond.notify_all();
    }

    void third(function<void()> printThird) {
        // cout<<3<<endl;
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(mtx);
        cond.wait(lk,[this](){return flag==2;});
        // printThird() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
        printThird();
        flag=3;
        // cout<<33<<endl;
    }

    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cond;
    int flag=0;
};
```

Comment: please post a [mre]. As your class doesn't contain any threads then it doesn't need any mutexes, however if your class is called from multiple threads it might need mutexes.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your three element functions are supposed to be called by different threads. Thus you need to lock the mutex in each thread to protect the common variable `flag` from concurrent access. So you should uncomment `mtx.lock()` and `mtx.unlock()` in `first` to protect it there as well. Functions `second` and `third` apply a `unique_lock` as an alternative for that.

Always make sure to unlock the mutex before calling `cond.notify_all()` either by calling `mtx.unlock()` before or making the `unique_lock` a local variable of an inner code block as in `second`.

### Further advice

Put a `private:` before the element variables at the bottom of your class definition to protect them from outside access. That will ensure that `flag` cannot be altered without locking the mutex.

Comment: "Always make sure to unlock the mutex before calling cond.notify_all()" - Why? AFAIK its not necessary.

Comment: @sklott "The notifying thread does not need to hold the lock on the same mutex as the one held by the waiting thread(s); in fact doing so is a pessimization, since the notified thread would immediately block again, waiting for the notifying thread to release the lock."

Comment: "Not need to" and "should not to" is a little bit different, eh?

Comment: @sklott yeah the statement is vague in the answer.

Comment: And "_Notifying while under the lock may nevertheless be necessary when precise scheduling of events is required, e.g. if the waiting thread would exit the program if the condition is satisfied, causing destruction of the notifying thread's condition_variable. A spurious wakeup after mutex unlock but before notify would result in notify called on a destroyed object._" - Those spurious wakeups are terrible

Comment: If I do not lock the mutex, is there some logic error? Can you make an example? THX!

Comment: @Alfred If you do not lock the mutex you may assign a value to `flag` at the same time as another thread is reading `flag` as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @Alfred: Imagine your ``flag`` is for example a huge ``vector`` and a function is going to change all elements. Now, when that function has changed half of the elements another function in another thread gets executed and reads half of the old values and half of the new values, which would be inconsistent. The mutex will prevent that. Although it's unlikely that such happens to your ``flag`` it may also happen and would be risky code to not prevent that.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

Comment: Great note about getting the mutex. Shared variables protected by a mutex must use the mutex on every access, even when it's not apparently needed, as it additionally prevents the compiler and CPU from optimizing out variable reads and cache writebacks to main memory.

Comment: Calling signal outside the critical section is good advice, but may not result in best performance. It theoretically should prevent an extra sleep. However, the OS may attempt to schedule "intelligently". Ending the critical section (by unlocking the mutex) may be perceived as a good opportunity for a context switch. In this case, the thread will be pre-empted before it calls `signal`, resulting in a little longer delay before a waiting thread can run. I would still advise signaling outside the mutex, with the caveat that it is not necessary and not always the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary.

That your code produced correct output in this instance is besides the point. It is entirely possibly that `printFirst` might not be complete by the time`printSecond` is called. You need the mutex to prevent this and stop `printSecond` and `printThird`. from being ran at the same time.

Comment: I cannot agree. Even if ```printSecond``` is called firstly, it will be blocked until `printFirst ` finished. @QCTDev

Comment: ahh i see the `cond.wait` now. with that you wont need the mutex or the other locks. i would prefer the mutex/lock paradigm since your intent is more obvious.

Comment: @QCTDev He will still need the mutex to make sure writing to and reading from `flag` doesn't happen at the same time.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if it's just `flag` left to protect then `flag` should be made `atomic`.

Comment: @QCTDev That'd introduce one level of locking on top of the already existing mutex that was supposed to protect `flag` that `second` and `third` uses.  The correct way to do it would be to use the same locking pattern in `first` as is used in `second` and `third`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not saying it isn't. We do agree that the mutex is the optimum solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `flag` checking condition in `second()` or `third()` may be evaluated at the same time as `first()` assigns `1` to `flag`.

Rewrite this

```
cond.wait(lk, [this](){return flag==1;});
```

like this and it may be easier to see:

```
while(!(flag==1)) cond.wait(lk);
```

It does the same thing as your `wait()` with a lambda.

`flag` is supposed to be read while the mutex is held - but `first` does not care about mutexes and assigns to `flag` whenever it pleases. For non-atomic types this is a disaster. It may *work* 10000000 times (and probably will) - but when things actually happen at the same time (because you let it) - **boom** - Undefined Behaviour

Comment: even atomic types exhibit this race condition

Comment: @AlanBirtles I was merely pointing at the race when having simultaneous r/w operations in the same memory location which would lead to UB - and that had it been an atomic, that wouldn't happen.